# Why does UISearchBar text field input stall, even though delegate textDidChange func returns quickly?

Tags: ios, swift, performance, task, searchbar

I have a UISearchBarDelegate textDidChange handler that does database lookups which may take a few seconds to complete.

The problem is, when I type text into the search bar, once it gets to the 3rd character input, e.g. the point where database lookup is initiated, search bar text input hangs - i.e. it won't echo a new character until table results are reloaded! At that point the iOS soft-keyboard momentarily shows an expanded view of the last key typed for a few seconds (normally it is displayed only for a fraction of a sec while typing as user feedback indicate which keys are pressed). But in this case the indicator hangs longer than acceptable, while input is blocked (queued up).

That's baffling, because I put the database lookup in its own (asynchronous) task and AFAIK database lookup should *not* be hanging the main thread. Thus, I think I should be able to type characters quickly and smoothly into the search bar, and database results will appear independently when available.  I used debug print statements to confirm the delegate method returns *before* the tableView reload is called, implying that indeed the Task is not stalling the main thread.

I'll also mention it is my assumption that as soon as I return from the delegate method that the textField should let new characters echo immediately... because the main thread is not tied to database delays.

What might be going wrong?

```
    //
    // MARK: UISearchBarDelegate methods
    //
    extension SearchForItViewController : UISearchBarDelegate {
        
        func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar,  textDidChange searchText: String) {
            if searchType == .stuff {
                someStuff.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)
            } else {
                someOtherStuff.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)
            }                
            if searchText.count == 0 {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                searchBar.searchTextField.font = UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
                return
            } else if searchText.count < 3 {
                return
            }
            searchBar.searchTextField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)

            let matchText = searchText.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines).capitalized
                        
            let matchTextLo = matchText
            let matchTextHi = matchText + "z"
            
            var someStuffTemporary : [Stuff]! = nil
            Task {
                switch searchScope {
                case .global:
                    do {
                        someStuffTemporary  =  try boringStuff(matchTextLo, matchTextHi, limit: 50, offset: 0)
                        someStuffTemporary  += try coolStuff(matchTextLo, matchTextHi, limit: 50, offset: 0)
                    } catch { print("Error fetching things for search term \"\(matchText)\"") }

                case let .otherStuffSpecific(_, stuffIdentifier):
                    if stuffId == "otherStuff" {
                        do {
                            stuffListTemporary = try otherStuff(matchTextLo, matchTextHi, limit: 50, offset: 0)
                        } catch { print("Error fetching things from otherStuff. Search term \"\(matchText)\"") }
                    } else {
                        do {
                            stuffListTemporary = try strangeStuff(matchTextLo, matchTextHi,
                                                                       otherStuffCode: stuffId, limit: 50, offset: 0)
                        } catch { print("Error fetching things from strangeStuff. Search term \"\(matchText)\"") }
                    }
                }
                self.stuffList = stuffListTemporary
                tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure sounds like the main thread is blocked.

You should use the debugger to investigate: set a breakpoint in your `Task`'s block, and take a look at what thread it's executing on, and what's going on in other threads in the app.

It looks like you're using a `Task` but its work is all synchronous. So if it's running on the main actor it will block the main thread until its done. Perhaps `Task.detached` will help.

Comment: Thanks. Will check it out! I am also using sqlite.swift library under the hood, and I wonder if it's somehow doing the work on the main thread regardless of what I'm doing.   I'll keep researching it. Thanks for the ideas.

Comment: Interesting: I did Task.detached and I had to make related changes to references. I had to momentarily comment out the line where I try to set the stored property the tableview data source loads from because it can't be mutated from a different actor, so the table didn't load, HOWEVER, the search bar text field did *not* pause. So now I just need to cross that last bridge and maybe that solves it.

Comment: Yes! That's a good thing -- `UITableView` isn't thread safe, you can only do things to it on the main actor. The compiler sees that you're trying to break that rule and is stopping you. You should be able to say `await self.tableView.reloadData()` to await it executing on the main actor.

Comment: I can't because the textDidChange delegate func sig doesn't match if I add async & w/o that I can't do await from main.